# Gatsby, Loading images in nested directories

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm creating a portfolio with Gatsby, and I wanted to use the gatsby-image for its optimizations, but I'm stuck.

I have a `projects` directory, inside which I have an individual directory for each of my projects, and in each directory I have the images of that project. Like this:

```
images
    |_ project1
    |       |_ image1.png
    |       |_ image2.png
    |       |_ ...
    |
    |_ project2
    |       |_ image1.png
    |       |_ image2.png
    |       |_ ...
    |
    |_ ...
```

First of all, on the main page, I want to show a gallery of all the projects, and this means that I need to get the first image of each directory (to use as thumbnail image) and have access to it in a format like this or something similar:

```
{
    "project1": [some image object],
    "project2": [some image object],
    "project3": [some image object],
    ...
}
```

And then when the user clicks on each project, I need to pop up a carousel and show them the rest of the images of that project.

So in total, I need to either be able to access my images in a hierarchical order, or to be able to use variables in the graphql query. pretty straight-forward and simple you might think! But neither is possible. So I'm stuck.

I also have the option to have the images paths in a json file if it helps (I already load my contents from a json). Something like this:

```
{
    project1: {
        /* other project's data */,
        images: [
            "/projects/project1/image1.png",
            "/projects/project1/image2.png",
            ...
        ]
    },
    project2: {
        /* other project's data */,
        images: [
            "/projects/project2/image1.png",
            "/projects/project2/image2.png",
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

**So please tell me how should one implement this portfolio using Gatsby and gatsby-image?**